# Terraform - How to get GCP folder ID by folder name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to get the GCP folder ID by folder name using Terraform data.

I've tried to use [google_active_folder](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/active_folder) & [google_folder](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/folder) but unfortunately without any success because the folder arguments of the Folder is in the form {folder_id} or folders/{folder_id}.

The TF data resource below get information about folder by id (12345) instead of the name I need.

```
data "google_folder" "my_folder_1" {
  folder              = "folders/12345"
}
output "get_folder_id" {
  value = data.google_folder.my_folder_1.id
}
```

**Terraform Error:**
[image]

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of your TF code? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: Sure, please see my TF code in the question above.

Comment: Sorry, its still not clear. What's wrong with your TF code? It does not work? Any errors?

Comment: I don't want to insert the folder ID 12345 I would like to get this value by passing the folder name to data.google_folder.my_folder_1 and unfortunately this is not supported.
If I pass the folder name I get an error that it is not found

Comment: Hi @Marcin please see the screenshot of my error when I try to get the GCP folder ID by the GCP folder name.